# How do I create a "Me" contact in android 4.0 and above

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

In my Sync Adapter for Android 4.0 and above, I want to create a "Me" account like Google+ and HaxSync are successfully creating.

Googling all day long, I could find no way to identify this specific contact though. Is there a documented way to create that entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's used only for Google+ for sure, and I suppose HaxSync does it that way as well.

The ID is called your "profile". See
["The User Profile"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#UserProfile). You should avoid changing it.